# How to keep a docker container running some background processes

Tags: docker, background-process, gnu-screen, docker-run

I have a python script that launches multiple programs in different screen sessions (gnu screen: terminal multiplexer) and exits.

The screen sessions keep running in the background.

Everything works fine when I run the script directly on my host machine.

Now, I dockerized the entire thing. But docker containers exit after the script finishes.

```
docker run -d myimage
```

After reading a bit, I realized that this is the normal behavior of docker. if no foreground process is running it will exit.

But I want to keep the docker container up, what should I do?

I saw, that running with `-it` flag, keeps it up. But I want to detach from the container, yet keep it up.

Comment: Create a foreground process in python that never ends.. depending on your program maybe a while True loop in main just calling asyncio.sleep(number) or create a thread with while True: time.sleep(number)

Comment: exactly, i have done that only. i believe this while true infinite loop, does not consume much cpu and memory, and the background processes will not be affected ?

Comment: Hard to tell for sure without any knowledge about your source code. time.sleep blocks your thread but not the process. If you have a thread just doing the idle stuff it doesn't hurt no one. CPU and MEM are not used at all. You can monitor it with htop or something..

Comment: Can you replace your launcher script entirely with Compose; instead of launching subprocesses in separate Screen windows, have Compose launch them in separate Docker containers?

Comment: hi david and araisch can  you tell whats best for me https://github.com/aahnik/telewater 

please see the entrypoint.py and Dockerfile, thank you